# Publishing stream appears with no images - Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I am building a small facebook application using the Facebook developer toolkit 3.0 in c#. I had this piece of code that used to work  a week ago. From some reason, when I try publishing my feed it appears without an image and without a Flash movie. Here is my code:

```
string userName = FacebookAPI.Users.GetInfo().name;
string message = "";

attachment attach = new attachment();

attach.href = string.Format(@"http://apps.facebook.com/{0}/?uId={1}&uName={2}", Consts.APP_NAME, ViewerUserId, userName);

attachment_media_flash flash = new attachment_media_flash();
flash.type = attachment_media_type.flash;
flash.expanded_width = 320;
flash.expanded_height = 260;
flash.height = 100;
flash.width = 130;

message = "";
attach.name = ""
attach.caption = "this works";
attach.description = ""
flash.imgsrc = string.Format(@"{0}/flash/Pinguin.JPG", Consts.DOMAIN_NAME);
flash.swfsrc = string.Format(@"{0}/flash/pinguin.swf", Consts.DOMAIN_NAME);

List<attachment_media> attach_media_list = new List<attachment_media>();
attach_media_list.Add(flash);

attach.media = attach_media_list;


/* action links */
List<action_link> actionlink = new List<action_link>();

action_link al1 = new action_link();
al1.href = string.Format(@"http://apps.facebook.com/{0}", Consts.APP_NAME);
al1.text = "myApp";

actionlink.Add(al1);
FacebookAPI.Stream.Publish(message, attach, actionlink, null , Convert.ToInt64   (ViewerUserId));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

1: The URL you pass is not the one that of the FB app, like `http://apps.fb.co/whatever/image.jpg`; 
it should be your domain URL, like `http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg`.

2: You need to pass the full URL of the image including the protocol (`http://` / `https://`),  like this:
`http://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg`

The following is wrong:

`www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg`